# Python list of lists behaving strange

Tags: python

This is likely a duplicate question but it is different in that the error occurs when I am using for loops. To explain, if I have list:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

and I do

```
x[0][0] = 5
```

The list will change to

```
[[5,2,3],[5,2,3],[5,2,3]]
```

A comment pointed out the above may be incorrect, below is output directly from the console:

```
>>> x = Board()
>>> x.create(6,6)
[['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '']]
>>> x.board
[['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '']]
>>> x.board[0][1]
''
>>> x.board[0][1] = 1
>>> x.board
[['', 1, '', '', '', ''], ['', 1, '', '', '', ''], ['', 1, '', '', '', ''], ['', 1, '', '', '', ''], ['', 1, '', '', '', ''], ['', 1, '', '', '', '']]
>>>
```

The solution described in other answers involve creating a for loop to create a new list element, however I'm not sure how to implement that in my code, shown below-

```
class Board():
   def create(self, rows, cols):
        self.board = []
        col_template = []
        for col in range(cols):
                col_template.append("")
        for row in range(rows):
            self.board.append(col_template)
        return self.board
```

Where `rows, cols` are some even integers

Comment: Nope it does not. Your example is incorrect.

Comment: So what is the error champ?

Comment: @Marcin added console output, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

```
  self.board.append(col_template[:])
```

Otherwise, your board will have references to the same array.

Your correct example should be:

```
a=[1,2,3]
x = [a,a,a]
x[0][0] = 5
print(x) # [[5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3]]
```

To fix the above problem:

```
a=[1,2,3]
x = [a[:],a[:],a[:]]
x[0][0] = 5
print(x) # [[5, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

This happens because x stores only references to the same list a. You need explicitly create copies (done by `a[:]`) of `a` to have different sublists in x.